# LDAP RabbitMQ AD Group failing to authorize

Tags: rabbitmq, ldap

I am looking integrate the rabbitmq with LDAP and allows administrator access who are in the mentioned AD Group.

configuration files

rabbitmq.conf

```
auth_backends.1 = ldap
auth_ldap.servers.1  = example.com
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_attribute = sAMAccountName
auth_ldap.dn_lookup_base = OU=Standard,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
auth_ldap.user_dn_pattern = ${username}
auth_ldap.use_ssl    = false
auth_ldap.port       = 389
auth_ldap.log        = network_unsafe
```

advanced.config

```
[{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,[
 {tag_queries,           [{administrator, {in_group,     "rabbitusers_group,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com","member"}},
                          {management,    {constant,true}}]}
]}].
```

getting same even auth_ldap.dn_lookup_attribute sAMAccountName replaced with distinguishedName
I noticed in log --- user have tag administrator? false

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [rabbitmq LDAP authentication for AD Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75363991/12567365), which you asked recently. Instead of creating a duplicate question, you should edit/improve the original question. And then you can delete this duplicate.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/m6dtcUOe3jY/m/qvwSc3oCBAAJ